# Is there anyway to watch the state of static variables of classes throughout debugging in code blocks?

Tags: c++, class, oop, debugging, codeblocks

I noticed with the watches addition on the debugger I can only see the state of the static variables of classes when I make an object from that class. But want to always be watching the static variables, is this possible?

Comment: I don't use codeblocks. But my guess is adding a watch as `MyClass::myStaticVariable` should work. Another (but ugly) way is the  memory view. There should be an option to view the application memory. So, find the address of your variable, setup the memory to show it and track the changes on it.

Comment: Stop using integrated gdb plugin, start using gdb from command line. Infinite possibilities which integrated solution cannot provide.

Comment: The problem may be that your class is not declared static. If it is, the static constructor should kick in at the start of your program and the class may pop into existence to the debugger.